llama-index with huggingfaceinterface api not returning the entire answer
I am building a RAG app with llama-index to extract information from invoice pdfs,here is how I am generating the query
    llm = HuggingFaceInferenceAPI(
        model_name="https://api-inference.huggingface.co/models/mistralai/Mistral-7B-Instruct-v0.2",
        token=HF_TOKEN
    )
    index = build_index(CHUNK_SIZE, llm, embeddings, client, INDEX_NAME)
    query_engine = index.as_query_engine(
        streaming=False,
        response_mode="compact"
    )

but the output is
invoice_number: 61356291
invoice_date: 09/06/2012
client_name: Rodriguez-Stevens
client_address: 2280 Angela Plain, Hortonshire, MS 93248
client_tax_id: 939-98-8477
seller_name: Chapman, Kim and Green
seller_address: 64731 James Branch, Smithmouth, NC 26872
seller_tax_id: 949-84-9105
iban: GB50ACIE59715038217063
names_of_invoice_items: ["Wine Glasses Goblets Pair Clear", "With Hooks Stemware Storage Multiple Uses Iron Wine Rack Hanging Glass", "Replacement Corkscrew Parts Spiral Worm Wine Opener Bottle Houdini", "HOME ESSENTIALS GRADIENT STEMLESS WINE GLASSES SET OF

as you can see the output is incomplete there were supposed to be 2 more rows why the output is not complete?
the output should be complete
